# Drag down autocomplete date in excel. With AM and PM

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can I drag down dates with AM and PM?

1. 22/11/2011 AM
2. 22/11/2011 PM
3. 23/11/2011 AM
4. 23/11/2011 PM

like that?

Comment: Don't think it's possible, personally i would create 2 columns (1xAM, 1xPM) then merge them together and then sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

1. Type your starting date in cell A1 but *don't type 'AM'* - a date without a time in Excel is effectively 12:00 AM.
2. Apply a custom number format `dd/mm/yyyy AM/PM` to cell A1.
3. In cell A2 enter the formula `=A1+0.5` which is effectively 12:00 PM on the same date.
4. Now you can drag down from A2 and you'll get the sequence you want.